# Require that type parameter have specific size?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to bound the type parameter `T` here with the constraint `size_of::<T>() == 4`, so that this function compiles (and so that any usage site of `foo` fails if the provided type is in fact not size 4?

```
// I want this to compile
fn foo<T>(t: T) where T: Sized {
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<T, [u8; 4]>(t); };
}

// and this not to compile
fn bar() {
  let x = [0u8; 5];
  foo(x);
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way. The next best thing would be to declare your own trait and only implement it on things you know are the right size. It would also be worth adding an assert in `foo()` to double check.

Comment: If there were a way, it would mean size changes could be breaking changes. But crates aren't required to bump their major versions when they change struct layout or size. That leads me to believe it's not possible to gate compilation on type size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make compilation fail for any call with size of non-4, but this will not make the transmute work. You need to use `transmute_copy()`:

```rust
fn foo<T>(t: T) {
    struct AssertSize4<T>(T);
    impl<T> AssertSize4<T> {
        const ASSERT: () = if std::mem::size_of::<T>() != 4 {
            panic!("size is not 4 bytes");
        };
    }
    let _ = AssertSize4::<T>::ASSERT;
    let t = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(t);
    unsafe {
        std::mem::transmute_copy::<T, [u8; 4]>(&*t);
    };
}
```

Beware that this will generate a *post-monormphization* error, meaning it'll succeed `cargo check` but fail `cargo build`.

However, your code is still incorrect: the size of something being 4 bytes *doesn't mean* it can be freely converted to 4 bytes. Take this struct, for example:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct Evil {
    _a: u8,
    _b: u16,
}
```

The size of this struct is four bytes, but passing it to `foo()` will invoke Undefined Behavior. This is because it has padding bytes, which are equivalent to uninitialized bytes (another example of unitialized memory is an uninitialized [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html)). [Transmuting uninitialized bytes to any type that does not allow uninitialized bytes, and that includes integers such as `u8`, is immediate Undefined Behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html#behavior-considered-undefined).

One possibility is to transmute the data into `[MaybeUninit<u8>; 4]`. But you may never assume this bytes are initialized, by doing operations such as [`assume_init()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.assume_init-1) on them.

Another operation is to make sure the bytes are initialized. So, how do you accept only types with only initialized bytes?

You cannot. Your only chance is creating an `unsafe trait OnlyInitialized` and unsafely impl it for types. You might want to also provide a derive macro for it (but the checks are subtle! don't assume you can just think of all of them). At this point, just use [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck).